# WCF the keyword not supported 'metadata' invalid-operations

Tags: c#, ado.net

So im quite new to WCF programming, i have an odd metadata error from my connection string

web.config

```
<add name="ApiConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/IdentityManagementDataContract.csdl|res://*/IdentityManagementDataContract.ssdl|res://*/IdentityManagementDataContract.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-PC;initial catalog=test-alliance;user id=XX;password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Has anyone an idea why my c# won't read the metadata from the web.config

my code is failing here

```
public static string GenerateApiEdmxConnectionString(String connectionString)
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

any ideas please will help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you passed is not a valid database connection string; this would be an Entity Framework Connection String, with SQL connection being its provider. You need to then build a  `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
```

This way you can add in the metadata required same before only in parts